# Data Frame issue in R

Tags: r

I am getting the following error when I am run the below code in R. All I want to do is to find the differences between two data sets.

```
setA <- c(1,3,9)
setB <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
removedfromsetA <- setdiff(setA,setB)
addedtosetB <- setdiff(setB,setA)

commoncolumns <- intersect(setA,setB)

Comparions <- data.frame(removedfromsetA,addedtosetB)
```

Error:

```
Error in data.frame(removedfromsetA, addedtosetB) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 5
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: The error is actually pretty clear: You cannot have different numbers of rows in your columns. Either use a different layout for your data frame (look up “tidy data”) or don’t use a data frame here.

Comment: As others have said, the problem is that columns of the `data frame` must be the same length.  If you want to store different length objects in a single variable, you should use a `list` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a data frame with as first column a column with 2 rows and as second column a column with 5 rows. This is not going to work. Just stay with `setdiff` and `intersect`, these can perfectly help you to figure out the difference between the two sets.

If you want to store the results you are better off with a list,

```
Comparisons <- list(removedfromsetA = removedfromsetA, addedtosetB = addedtosetB)
```

Thanks to @barker

Comment: Depending on their data, it may take a significant amount of time to compute `setdiff` or `intersect` and if they need to use the values over and over that could add a lot run time to their code.  Wanting to store the values is not unreasonable, they just can't use a `data frame` to do it; they need a list.